# HTML Table - Track Selections for Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've created a simple table using Bootstrap and PHP which looks like this:

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Select</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="RFIT1000">
      <td>Penny Lane</td>
      <td>10/03/2015</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Yes</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">No</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="RFIT1001">
      <td>Fred Kruger</td>
      <td>18/01/2016</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Yes</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">No</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="RFIT1002">
      <td>Bob Hope</td>
      <td>09/08/2016</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Yes</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">No</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is part of a form that will be submitted and I need to track which rows were selected Yes and which rows were selected No. I would also like to add a .success class to the table row when Yes is clicked (and remove a .danger class if previously present), and when No is clicked add a . danger class to the table row (and remove a . success class if previously present).

If the user clicks Yes I would like to track the id value for the Row in a variable/array somehow and the same for the No selections. If the user changes a selection it should also remove the value from the original variable/array - e.g. if they first clicked No and then they click Yes it should add the value to the 'Yes' variable/array list and remove it from the 'No" variable/array list.

I'm still learning HTML, Javascript and CSS as I'm going so not sure what the best approach here is and how to implement a system that tracks selections and makes those available as POST values to include in the form submission?

Comment: Don't you want to use checkbox instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
var store={};
//store all values of succes fauilure in an object coresponding to the id 
$("[id^=RFIT]").each(function(e,i){store[i.id]=$(i).hasClass('success')?'success':'danger'});


//on click update the closest tr class and store
$('button').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('btn-success')){
        result='success';
    }else{
        result='danger';
    }
    $(this).closest('tr').attr('class',result);
   store[ $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')]=result;
});
```

Comment: here the store holds initially all id set to danger, since none are selected initially

Comment: Thanks @nive32 that is almost perfect. Can I have 2 different scripts that run for each of the Yes and No buttons and track the values separately to each other?

Comment: $('button .btn-success').click(function(){ $(this).closest('tr').attr('class','success');
   store[ $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')]='success';} similarly for danger class u can get it

Comment: thanks @nive32 - final question do you know how I can pass the store value to an html form to submit to my PHP page?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Select</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="RFIT1000">
      <td>Penny Lane</td>
      <td>10/03/2015</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label><input name="row1" id="row1Y" type="radio" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Yes</label>
        <label><input name="row1" id="row1N" type="radio" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">No</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id="RFIT1001">
      <td>Fred Kruger</td>
      <td>18/01/2016</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label><input name="row2" id="row2Y" type="radio" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Yes</label>
        <label><input name="row2" id="row2N" type="radio" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">No</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="RFIT1002">
      <td>Bob Hope</td>
      <td>09/08/2016</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label><input name="row3" id="row3Y" type="radio" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Yes</label>
        <label><input name="row3" id="row3N" type="radio" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">No</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use radio button to get user response also you can provide id to those radio button to catch event in java script using that you can change classes of row at run time.
Hope it will help you, still if any doubt ask me I will provide java script code too.
I have used same name to radio buttons in one row as to read input in PHP and different id to handle different event in java script.